# Write the definition of prime number using symbols and no words

Tags: solution-verification

I'm trying to write the definition of prime numbers using only symbols.
Here is what I have:
A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers.

Note:

N$^{*}$ is the set of all natural numbers except for $0$.

So the set of prime numbers is S = {x $\in$ N$^{*}$, x $\neq$ 1 $|$ ... [I'm stuck here]}

I don't know how to explain. I was just introduced to proofs and sets so I do not want to use complex symbols. Can someone suggest me a simple way for the "such that" part, please?
Thank you!

Comment: Consider this: $x\gt1$ $\land\, \forall a,b\in\mathbb N^*$, $ab=x\implies a=x\lor b=x$

Comment: Or $p\mid ab \Longrightarrow p\mid a \vee p\mid b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S = \{ x \in \mathbb{N}, x \neq 1 | \forall p,q \in \mathbb{N},\  pq=x \implies p,q \in \{1, x\} \}$$